# I use the bitset as the parameter of function,it is wrong, however , I do not know why?

Tags: c++, parameters, bitset

as greenhand to use bitset data type, I want to use the one bit of bitset type data as the input 
of function,however the bitset data used as parameter seems to be wrong, while I do not know where 
is the problem.  the below is the code used to test?

```
bitset<1> fun_1(bitset<1>a,bitset<1>b)
    {
    return (a^b);
    }
void main()
{
  bitset<4> res;
  bitset<4> input1,input2;
  res[1]=fun_1(input1[0],input2[0]);
  return;
}
```

Comment: `operator[]` on a bitset returns a `bool` (ish, there's some lvalue magic), not a smaller bitset.

Comment: Also, it's `int main()`